# Adding sets not containing arithmetic progressions of length three by forcing

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, arithmetic-progression

Consider the following forcing notion: conditions in $\mathbb{P}$ are pairs $(s, N),$ where:

1) $s\in 2^{<\omega}$,

2) $N\in \mathbb{N}$,

3) (by identifying $s$ with a subset of $lh(s)$)  $s$ contains no arithmetic progressions of length $3$, and $\Sigma_{n\in s}1/n \geq N$.

The ordering is defined in the natural way: $(t, M)\leq (s,N)$ iff $t$ extends $s$ and $M\geq N.$

Now let $G$ be $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $V$, and let $R=\bigcup\{s: \exists N, (s,N)\in G    \}.$ We can imagine $R$ as a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. The following is clear:

**Claim 1.** $R$ contains no arithmetic progressions of length three.

Given any finite $M$, consider the set $D_M=\{(s, N)\in \mathbb{P}: N\geq M \}.$
Then

**Claim 2.** If for each $N$, the set $D_N$ is dense in $\mathbb{P},$ then $R$ is a large set of natural numbers, i.e., $\Sigma_{n\in R}1/n=\infty$  (and hence $R$ witnesses a counterexample to the famous Erdos-Turan conjecture).

> **Question.** Suppose $(s, N)\in \mathbb{P}.$ is there $t\in 2^{<\omega}$ extending $s$ such that $(t, N+1)\in \mathbb{P}?$

Of course a positive answer to  the above question implies that all $D_M$'s are dense.

**Remark.** If such an $R$ exists in an extension, then it already exists in the ground model.

Comment: Just as a side remark: the machinery of forcing seems like overkill here.  Suppose your question is answered positively, say by some construction sending $(s,N)$ to $(f(s),N+1)$.  Then just start with $s_0 = \emptyset$, and iterate $f$ from $(s_0,0)$ to get a sequence of conditions $(s_n, n)$; now $S = \bigcup_n s_n$ gives a counterexample to Erdos-Turan.

Comment: Yes, this is clear, just note that we need to meet countably many dense sets, and we can find the generic filter meeting these dense sets in the ground model, this is why I wrote the remark above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "yes" answer to your question is equivalent to the statement "there exists a large set of natural numbers that admits no arithmetic progression of length three."  I'm submitting the proof of this equivalence as an answer since I don't expect to see an actual answer unless it shows up in Annals too :)

So, to the proof.  You've already noted the forward direction.

For the backward direction, suppose $A$ is a large set of natural numbers with no arithmetic progression of length three, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and $s\subseteq k$ has no arithmetic progressions of length three.  We'll show that there's a large set $B$ such that $B\cap k = s$, and $B$ has no arithmetic progressions of length three.  This is clearly sufficient.

The "naiive" choice for $B$ is the set $s\cup (A\setminus k)$, which is large and has no length-3 AP's which are entirely below $n$ or entirely above $k$; but of course there may be an AP of length 3 which crosses $k$.  There are only finitely-many APs of length 3 with two points in $s$, so we may remove the corresponding points from $A$ (if they exist) and still have a large set.  So we'll assume that we've already done this, i.e. $A\cap k = \emptyset$, and there are no APs of length 3 with two points in $s$.

If the AP has two points in $A$, then it's more complicated.  Suppose $i\in s$.  Let $B_i$ be the set you get from $A$ by removing the possible third points, i.e. $$ B_i = A\setminus\{2n - i \;|\; n\in A\}$$  We'll show that $B_i$ is still large.  Let $N$ be a large natural number. Note that $$ \sum_{n\in B_i\cap N} \frac{1}{n} \ge \sum_{n\in A\cap N} \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n-i}$$  If $n$ is large enough, say $n > 3i$, then $\frac{1}{2n - i} < \frac{2}{3n}$, so if $A\cap 3k = \emptyset$ then the above sum is at least $$ \sum_{n\in A\cap N} \frac{1}{3n} = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n\in A\cap N} \frac{1}{n} $$  Hence, as the sums on the right go to $\infty$ as $N\to\infty$, it follows that $B_i$ is large.

Applying this process multiple times, once for each member of $s$, we eventually get a large set $B$ such that $s\cup B$ has no AP's of length 3.